# Как можно упростить javascript проверку на валидность?

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода, валидация

Я новичок в javascript, и у меня есть вопрос. У меня есть код с проверкой на валидность заполнение регистрационной формы. Я думал как ее можно упростить и пришел к выводу, что нужно создать отдельный метод и туда передавать нужные мне параметры, но столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю с какого места их лучше передавать. Как это сделать лучше и правильно?

```
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");
var emailPattern = new RegExp("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,5})$");
var passwordPattern = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,20}$");

document.getElementById("registration_form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
  var lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confPass").value;
    document.getElementById("error_first_name").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("error_last_name").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("error_email").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("error_password").innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById("error_confirmPassword").innerHTML = '';

  if (!namePattern.test(fName)) {
    document.getElementById("error_first_name").innerHTML = 'Wrong first name! range: [4-20] and not contain numbers';
    event.preventDefault();
  } if (!namePattern.test(lName)) {
    document.getElementById("error_last_name").innerHTML = 'Wrong last name! range: [4-20] and not contain numbers';
    event.preventDefault();
  } if(!emailPattern.test(email)){
    document.getElementById("error_email").innerHTML = 'Wrong email! Your email should contains this symbols: [-_A-z0-9]';
    event.preventDefault();
  } if(!passwordPattern.test(password)){
    document.getElementById("error_password").innerHTML = 'Wrong password! range: [8-20], minimum one upper case letter: [A] and minimum one figure';
    event.preventDefault();
  } if(confirmPassword != password){
    document.getElementById("error_confirmPassword").innerHTML = 'Your passwords do not match';
    event.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Моя форма:

```
<form action="" id="registration_form">
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_first_name" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">First Name: </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="Your first name" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_last_name" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Last Name: </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Your last name" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_email" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Email: </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your email" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_password" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Password: </li>
                        <li><input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Your password" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_confirmPassword" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Re-enter Password:</li>
                        <li><input type="password" id="confPass" placeholder="Confirm your password" value=""></li>
                    </ul>

                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register Now">
                    <p class="click">By clicking this button, you agree to my modern style <a>Policy Terms and Conditions</a> to Use</p>
                </form>
```

Я пытаюсь уменьшить свой код, для этого я создал функцию, в которой передаю все параметры, которые мне нужны, но что я не делаю правильно. Теперь это выглядит так.

```
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");
var emailPattern = new RegExp("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,5})$");
var passwordPattern = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,20}$");

document.getElementById("registration_form").addEventListener("submit", function(event){
function getParam(value, pattern, error_value, error_message){
    error_value.innerHTML = '';
    if(!pattern.test(value)){
        error_value.innerHTML = error_message;
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
})
```

Но то, что я делаю, неверно, как я могу улучшить его и правильно передать мои параметры? Нужно ли передавать их с помощью html или как лучше будет это реализовать?

Comment: как ни странно, для доброй половины этого можно использовать `data`-атрибуты соответствующих полей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все с комментариями.

Примечание: элементы ошибок должны начинатся с error_ и дальше должно быть написано имя поля которое в errorInfo(`first_name`, `last_name` и т.д), то есть быть вот таким: `error_first_name`, `error_last_name` и т.д

```js
var namePattern = new RegExp("^([A-z]{4,20})$");
var emailPattern = new RegExp("^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,5})$");
var passwordPattern = new RegExp("^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,20}$");

document.getElementById("registration_form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // достаточно написать один раз
  
  var fName = document.getElementById("fName").value;
  var lName = document.getElementById("lName").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("pass").value;
  var confirmPassword = document.getElementById("confPass").value;
  
  // набор полей ошибок
  var errorInfo = {
    first_name: { // имя поля(потом находит элемент по нему document.getElementById('error_' + name)) 
      // валидное ли поле? если true то не будет ошибки
      validity: namePattern.test(fName), 
      // сообщение об ошибке
      text: 'Wrong first name! range: [4-20] and not contain numbers' 
    },
    last_name: { 
      validity: namePattern.test(lName),
      text: 'Wrong last name! range: [4-20] and not contain numbers'
    },
    email: {
      validity: emailPattern.test(email),
      text: 'Wrong email! Your email should contains this symbols: [-_A-z0-9]'
    },
    password: {
      validity: passwordPattern.test(password),
      text: 'Wrong password! range: [8-20], minimum one upper case letter: [A] and minimum one figure'
    },
    confirmPassword: {
      validity: confirmPassword === password,
      text: 'Your passwords do not match'
    }
  }
  // перебирает errorInfo, name - имя поля(ключ объекта errorInfo)
  for (let name in errorInfo) {
    var errorMsg = ''; // текст ошиьки, изначально ставит ошибку как ее нет
    
    // если поле не валидное
    if (!errorInfo[name].validity)
      errorMsg = errorInfo[name].text; // ставит текст ошибки
      
    // ставит текст ошибки (innerHTML медленее textContent)
    document.getElementById('error_' + name).textContent = errorMsg;
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="" id="registration_form">
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_first_name" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">First Name: </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="fName" placeholder="Your first name" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_last_name" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Last Name: </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Your last name" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_email" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Email: </li>
                        <li><input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your email" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_password" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Password: </li>
                        <li><input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Your password" value=""></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul>
                        <div id="error_confirmPassword" style="color: #ff0000"></div>
                        <li class="text-info">Re-enter Password:</li>
                        <li><input type="password" id="confPass" placeholder="Confirm your password" value=""></li>
                    </ul>

                    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register Now">
                    <p class="click">By clicking this button, you agree to my modern style <a>Policy Terms and Conditions</a> to Use</p>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Все маски можно ввести в `data-` атрибуты (о бессмысленности валидации e-mail регекспом можно почитать, например [здесь](https://habr.com/post/175375/))
2. Тексты ошибок можно вписать на страницу заранее и просто показывать/прятать блок
3. Все инпуты можно перебрать в цикле как дочерние к элементу `<ul>`

```js
document.getElementById("registration_form").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
  var blocks = this.querySelectorAll('ul');
  for (var i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++) {
    var input = blocks[i].querySelector('input');
    var msg = blocks[i].querySelector('.error');
    var pattern = input.getAttribute('data-pattern');
    var valid = false;
    if (pattern !== null) {
      var re = new RegExp(pattern);
      valid = re.test(input.value);
    } else
      valid = input.value == document.getElementById('pass').value;
    if (!valid) {
      msg.style.display = 'block';
      event.preventDefault();
    } else
      msg.style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

```css
.error {
  color: #ff0000;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="" id="registration_form">
  <ul>
    <div class="error">Wrong first name! range: [4-20] and not contain numbers</div>
    <li class="text-info">First Name: </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Your first name" data-pattern="^([A-z]{4,20})$" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="error">Wrong last name! range: [4-20] and not contain numbers</div>
    <li class="text-info">Last Name: </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Your last name" value="" data-pattern="^([A-z]{4,20})$">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="error">Wrong email! Your email should contains this symbols: [-_A-z0-9]</div>
    <li class="text-info">Email: </li>
    <li>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Your email" value="" data-pattern="^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,5})$">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="error">Wrong password! range: [8-20], minimum one upper case letter: [A] and minimum one figure</div>
    <li class="text-info">Password: </li>
    <li>
      <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Your password" value="" data-pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\\d)[a-zA-Z\\d]{8,20}$">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <div class="error">Your passwords do not match</div>
    <li class="text-info">Re-enter Password:</li>
    <li>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm your password" value="">
    </li>
  </ul>

  <input type="submit" value="Register Now">
  <p class="click">By clicking this button, you agree to my modern style <a>Policy Terms and Conditions</a> to Use</p>
</form>
```

Comment: Хорошее решение, но что если например, нужно добавить input file в котором проверить что файлов минимум 2 и размер не больше 2МБ? Не очень удобно получается.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько ТС хотел проверять только регекспами. Я предложил решение. Если нужна более хитрая проверка - нужно менять решение в зависимости от требований